# IdentityServer4: scope authentication attribute?

Tags: validation, scope, attributes, authorize-attribute, identityserver4

Just asking, is there any way to protect different controllers or actions with different scopes?
So far I have only seen one global scope for the whole app.

In identity server 3 there seems to have been a ScopeAuthorize attribute but I can't find it in IdentityServer4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/247 .
So you create a policy and then use that policy in the Authorize Attribute.